# How to pass dynamic value from java to sql(db2) IN statement

Tags: jdbc

I have to pass List from java to JDBC query( which i have written in xml file).

List  transactionTypeStringList which can have 3 or 6

Before passing it to query, i have joined all the list value using following code to concatenate

```
transactionTypeString=  String.join("',' ", transactionTypeStringList);

transactionTypeString= "'"+transactionTypeString+ "'";
```

Query:

```
select count(*) from transaction where transactiontype in (?);
```

I am using db2 db and when i run the program, i am getting following exception:

Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.64.96

When i googled this error code, it states that "Data being inserted into the database table column is larger than the assigned column length." which i understand since i am passing list of value to replace a single ?
But now I don't how to pass multiple value from java code to jdbc to replace a single ?.

I don't want to create multiple queries(one with 3 and other with 6 value). Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Please include the query that you are using to generate this error.  It will make answering your question much easier.  Also, when you say "replace a single ?", do you mean you are trying to put this data into a single column in the database?

Comment: Query: select count(*) from transaction where transactiontype in (?);   and yes, i will be going to put this data into single column